# How I can define in Sphinx which .rst files and directories should be used?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, autodoc

**How I can define in Sphinx which .rst files and directories should be used?**

I want to include an automatic documentation generator in my testing/building/documentation script.
*sphinx-quickstart* was executed in my workspace and created an index.rst-file. As Sphinx uses restructured text files for documentation I navigated through the workspace and create them manually with *sphinx-autogen*. It resulted into the tasks.rst file (see below).

When I use 'make html' I get several warnings:

> **WARNING**: invalid signature for automodule (u'tasks/add_to_config')
>
> **WARNING**: autodoc can't import/find module 'tasks.add_to_config', it reported error: "No module named wl_build.tasks", please check your spelling and sys.path
>
> **WARNING**: don't know which module to import for autodocumenting u'tasks/add_to_config' (try placing a "module" or "currentmodule" directive in the document, or giving an explicit module name)
>
> ...

**My index.rst**

```
Welcome to build's documentation!
====================================

Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

.. automodule:: tasks/add_to_config
   :members:

.. automodule:: tasks/build_egg
   :members:
```

**tasks.rst**

```
tasks Package
=============

:mod:`tasks` Package
--------------------

.. automodule:: tasks.__init__
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:

:mod:`add_to_config` Module
---------------------------

.. automodule:: tasks.add_to_config
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:

:mod:`build_egg` Module
-----------------------

.. automodule:: tasks.build_egg
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try replacing the `/` characters in your index.rst file with periods (`.`)

like this:

```
Welcome to build's documentation!
====================================

Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

.. automodule:: tasks.add_to_config
   :members:

.. automodule:: tasks.build_egg
   :members:
```

See if that helps.

If Sphinx still can't find the code to document, then you'll probably need to modify your `PYTHONPATH` or alter `sys.path` in your `conf.py` file in order to help Sphinx find what it's looking for.